# composer can not generate sf2 autoload files

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

To install vendors for Symfony 2.1.0 I'm running `php composer.phar install` but it gives error during `Generating autoload files`.

Error is:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in  on line 26
>
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

It works fine on localhost, but not on server. Not sure what the problem is with the php set up?

EDIT:

PHP is 5.3.13. I checked that beforehand.

I ran app/check.php and everything is OK, except warning for accelerator.

I could successfully install composer as well.

The composer.json has the same values as the 2.1 symfony-standard branch:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have php5.3 as cli on your server? `php -v` on the console should display you the installed php version.

Comment: Run composer installer to see if the error relates to composer: curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Comment: More likely, however, it is related to Symfony. So go to your project's directory and run Symfony checks: php app/check.php

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've edited my post. The problem still persists.

Comment: Please check that the values for the keys `symfony-app-dir` and `symfony-web-dir` in your composer.json don't contain any backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the whole `vendor/` directory (and eventually also `composer.lock`) and then try to run composer install again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host seems to use php5.2 by standard. sigh.

I made an alias in the .bash_profile to the php53 executable previously.

This did not get return with ScriptHandler::getPhp as it returned the default executable (5.2). I didn't pick it up as I'm used to the T_FUNCTION error being namespacing not recognised.

I could change my .bash_profile to use PATH instead of alias.

Seems resolved.